# I am following the video on youtube about adding datepicker, but it doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I am watching this video to learn integrate a calender to my webapp, but I cant do the same outcome.
here is the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0mrZwl1Kow&t=470s&ab_channel=LearnGoogleSpreadsheets

I am now working on the datepicker initialize, the the calender doesn't show up when I click in it.
here is the HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
<input id="prefDate" type="text" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

And here is my initialize js script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes); 
var datePicker1 = document.getElementById('prefDate');
M.Datepicker.init(datePicker1);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import the materialize.js from cdn by adding the following script tag in your HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: already have one in my html page, still now working

Comment: <HTML>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
     rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     
     
     
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script 
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"> 
      </script>
     <HTML>
it is what i have in my html page

Comment: you need to add that at the bottom - just before the closing `</body>` tag. Check out [this video](https://youtu.be/yu-nNEPw83k?t=73) which talks about this.